# Combining a url with urlunparse

Tags: python, urlparse

I'm writing something to 'clean' a URL. In this case all I'm trying to do is return a faked scheme as `urlopen` won't work without one. However, if I test this with `www.python.org` It'll return `http:///www.python.org`. Does anyone know why the extra /, and is there a way to return this without it?

```
def FixScheme(website):

   from urlparse import urlparse, urlunparse

   scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment = urlparse(website)

   if scheme == '':
       return urlunparse(('http', netloc, path, params, query, fragment))
   else:
       return website
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem is that in parsing the *very* incomplete URL `www.python.org`, the string you give is actually taken as the `path` component of the URL, with the `netloc` (network location) one being empty as well as the scheme.  For defaulting the scheme you can actually pass a second parameter `scheme` to `urlparse` (simplifying your logic) but that does't help with the "empty netloc" problem.  So you need some logic for *that* case, e.g.

```
if not netloc:
    netloc, path = path, ''
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense, it's assuming that the netloc exists as it's an empty string and concatenating the extra / that should be there. Your solution works!Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

It's because urlparse is interpreting "www.python.org" not as the hostname (netloc), but as the path, just as a browser would if it encountered that string in an href attribute.  Then urlunparse seems to interpret scheme "http" specially.  If you put in "x" as the scheme, you'll get "x:www.python.org".

I don't know what range of inputs you're dealing with, but it looks like you might not want urlparse and urlunparse.